# Transparent picture box on top of another picture box is not working. How to fix this?

Tags: c#, winforms, image, paint, picturebox

I want to create two picture boxes, overlapping. 
The first Picturebox is used as the background, the picture of the screen. 
using this method:

```
public void BckShow()
{
     Rectangle rect = Screen.GetBounds(this);
     gBackImg = Graphics.FromImage(bBackImg);
     gBackImg.CopyFromScreen(0,0,0,0,
               Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size,
               CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
}
```

The second picturebox is above the first one, a transparent picture box that can be drawn using this mouse event:

```
public void Draw(bool draw, Point sp, Point ep)
        {
            if (draw)
            {
                gCanvas.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
                pen = new Pen(new SolidBrush(ColorName), BrushSize);
                if (toolPen.Checked)
                {
                    gCanvas.DrawLine(pen, sp, ep);
                }
                else if (toolEreser.Checked)
                {
                    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(ep.X, ep.Y, BrushSize*5, BrushSize*5);
                    gCanvas.DrawEllipse(pen, rect);
                    gCanvas.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(ColorName), rect);
                }
                bCanvas.MakeTransparent(Color.White);
                pbxCanvas.Refresh();
                dirty = true;
                toolSave.Enabled = true;
            }
        }

        private void pbxCanvas_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            sp = e.Location;
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                ActivePaint = true;
            }
        }

        private void pbxCanvas_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            ActivePaint = false;
        }

        private void pbxCanvas_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            ep = e.Location;
            Draw(ActivePaint, sp, ep);
            sp = ep;
        }
```

but when i run the program, the second PictureBox does not draw anything when the mouse event was fired. how i can fix this?

I do this because I just want to save the image in the second picture box. Unlike PrintScreen but seemed to make notes on the screen and save the image apart from the screen image.

Is there another way to do this? like using controls other than picture box, or may directly use the screen as a background but still can save the image in the transparent PictureBox separately.

This is the example I want to achieve:

when drawing:
[image]

results stored images:

[image]

I hope you all will help me to fix this. sorry for poor explanation.

this the document outline window for more detail:
[image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of document outline window. That shows how your PictureBoxes are aligned on your Form.

Comment: @woni : yes of course you can see it above

Comment: Is your PictureBox docked in it's parent container, try painting in the upper left corner and check if the events are fired.

Comment: How can I know that? I have not been able to make the PictureBox it receives mouse events, when drawing from the top left corner.

Comment: @woni : Can you give me an email address that I can contact. I will send the source code that I have created. Maybe that would be easier to give Comments section which should be improved in order to make this code work. I would be very grateful if you spend a bit of your valuable time to see it.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that your surface being overdrawn by refresh.  You should be tracking what you want to draw, and then drawing it in the picture box's `Paint` event.  That way, you get handed a `Graphics` object and every refresh, you're drawing.

That's assuming, of course, that you have a valid, and correct, `Graphics` object in the first place.

BTW:  passing a form-scope variable to `Draw` is confusing, just use it.

Comment: but when I do not use a transparent picture box and use the background with white (not transparent), drawing with the above method can work well. of course I also have to eliminate this code `bCanva.MakeTransparent (Color.White)`.  MakeTransparent (Color.White). so how do I can draw on a transparent picturebox?

Answer (score 0):

Check your gCanvas initializer, if it is used from within Paint event (e.Graphics), then your changes are lost when you call the Refresh() method. Refresh() causes a new Paint event to be fired, creating a new Graphics object and therefore invalidating yours.
Create a new graphics object from your PictureBox's Image to persist your changes permanently.

```
private List<Point> points = new List<Point>();

private void pbxCanvas_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left) {
        ActivePaint = true;
    }
}

private void pbxCanvas_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
    ActivePaint = false;
    points.Clear();
}

private void pbxCanvas_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
    if (ActivePaint) {
        points.Add(e.Location);
        Refresh();
    }
}

private void pbxCanvas_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {
    using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(pbxCanvas.Image)) {
        for (int i = 0; i < points.Count - 1; i++) {
            graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, points[i], points[i + 1]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this solution today, and does not seem to work for me. transparent picture box that is on top still does not receive mouse events or draw any images. if you've tried it and it works for you?

Comment: Do you use a special kind of PictureBox? I tried that code yesterday with System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox

Comment: No, I just use a regular 2 overlapping PictureBox. 
The picturebox that I want to draw upon is above and has a transparent background color property.